# How to change unwanted partition key which is showing in Athena from AWS glue to regular column?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a column in Athena that is shown as a partition column but that is not what I intend. I am creating a table in Athena by ingesting parquet files from my S3 using a glue crawler.

I'm ingesting data from one S3 bucket to another through a glue ETL job. The job is taking unstructured data and turning into format.  I explicitly set my partition keys through the following code:

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
 frame = test_dyF,
    connection_type = 's3',
    connection_options= {'path':'s3://project/dev/table/region=eu/', 'partitionKeys':['year','month','day','hour']},
format='parquet',
transformation_ctx='test_ctx'
)
```

I have a glue crawler that takes the parquet data from the destination S3 bucket to Athena.

I tried to set the partition key in the ETL job but in Athena it shows that region is also a partition key. Is there a way I can change to a non-partioned column? Also, why would the glue crawler recognize that column as a partitioned column if it wasn't explicitely stated in the ETL job?

[image]

Comment: The path contains `/region=eu/` try without it. There's no metadata capturing partitioning other than the folder structure. My guess is that Athena discovering your root folder considers that there's a partition on `region`.

Comment: Thanks @MarcC.   I'm going to need the region in the S3 path. There are multiple regions this data needs to be divided into.  How should I go about capturing partitioning through metadata?

Comment: I'm confused in the initial question region was not a partitioning key. If you want to make it one, add it to the list and still remove the `/region=eu/` path `write_dynamic_frame` will create the appropriate subfolders.

Comment: That's right.  In the Glue ETL job, I did not put region as a partition key.  However, after the data went through the glue crawler into Athena it shows that region is a partition key, which is not what I want.  I still need to keep region as a subfolder.

Comment: Change the naming convention then, use one which does not look like a regular partition (ex. region-eu). You will have then a table per region.